Can't sign in to github BUT gh works with ssh key, but 2fa recovery states no valid ssh keys for recovery?
I have different github account for different organizations.  One which I use rather infrequently, I can't login into.  The password reset email works fine but apparently I signed up for 2FA and lost the recovery keys.  This doesn't make sense to me as I have well defined location for all recovery keys.
The truly odd part is that while I have a working SSH key to manage the repos via gh, M2FA recovery explicitly states that I have no valid ssh keys for recovery.
Since this is a free account, I can't contact support or I can't figure out how to navigate to a point where such would be possible.  I've gone around in circles with that.  Does anyone know how to reach a github support rep to sort this out?
$ mkdir help--cannot-login
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue
$ cd help--cannot-logingin
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ emacs README.md
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/phdyex/github-issue/help--cannot-login/.git/
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git add .
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git status
On branch main

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   README.md

(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git commit -minitial
[main (root-commit) 50215e7] initial
 1 file changed, 13 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ gh repo create help--cannot-login --public --source=. --remote=upstream
Γ£ô Created repository philip-h-dye/help--cannot-login on GitHub
Γ£ô Added remote git@github.com:philip-h-dye/help--cannot-login.git
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git remote -v
upstream        git@github.com:philip-h-dye/help--cannot-login.git (fetch)
upstream        git@github.com:philip-h-dye/help--cannot-login.git (push)
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ echo "\nextra line\n" >> README.md
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git status
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git add README.md
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git commit -m"Silly change"
[main 8f0dbe1] Silly change
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ git push origin main
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
(base) [ 2 ] xps-ne ~/github-issue/help--cannot-login
$ 

OK, so this is very odd.  My ssh key let's me create the repo but not push changes to it?
The repo is https://github.com/philip-h-dye/help--cannot-login.  It should have gotten the README.md with the message above but obviously did not despite supposedly being up to date.
I tried the M2FA recovery but it says there are no valid SSH keys for recovery.
I tried my single 2fa recovery key I have saved for github. Yes, I know it says it should be a set but I only have a single recovery key on file for github.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks,
Philip

In the support portal, choosing OTHER instead of any of the more accurate reasons, let's you create a support ticket.  The accurate reasons just lead one back in a fruitless circle.

So far, I've gotten what appears to be an automated reply restating github's stance on lost 2FA recovery keys.  I'm still not sure that I actually activated 2FA but I don't see why anyone would hack into any of my accounts.

I got a reply that included the month that the recovery codes were created and the OS to which they were downloaded.  That let me narrow down the search space enough to locate them in an old Backblaze backup.  Obviously, I had screwed up and not moved them where they I keep such codes.  Thank heaven for long backup retention!

Your git remote -v output says there's a remote named upstream but nothing named origin - so what happens if you run git push upstream main?
